# PowerShell to extract data from HTML URL

Tags: html, powershell

I'm looking to extract the worst % up-time for a service from our PRTG monitoring tool using PowerShell.  I have a sample table that shows several sensors for a specific service, in this case BIP Reports.  The Up-time / Downtime columns seem to be skewed so the Good / Failed columns have the best data.  A sample table is as follows, you can see I have several rows, I need to extract the worst up-time to report on:

[BIPReport](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Yh5th.jpg)

Looking at the "View Page Source" I see the following partial code (not all source provided here, just the part I need extracted):

```
</td>
<td class="rightalign">
    100 %<div class="colorflag" style="background-color:#00c000">&nbsp;</div><br>
    0 %<div class="colorflag" style="background-color:#00c000">&nbsp;</div>
</td>
<td class="rightalign">
    <span class="percent">[30d23h48m23s]</span><br>
    <span class="percent">[0s]</span>
</td>
<td class="rightalign">
    99.973 %<div class="colorflag" style="background-color:#00c000">&nbsp;</div><br>
    0.027 %<div class="colorflag" style="background-color:#00c000">&nbsp;</div>
</td>
<td>
    <span class="percent">[44628]</span><br>
    <span class="percent">[12]</span>
</td>
</tr>




        </table>
    </td>

        <td style="" class="rightalign">

        0 msec<br>

        </td>
        <td style="" class="rightalign">
            100 %<div class="colorflag" style="background-color:#00c000">&nbsp;</div><br>
            0 %<div class="colorflag" style="background-color:#00c000">&nbsp;</div>
        </td>
        <td style="" class="rightalign">
            <span class="percent">[30d23h48m23s<br>
            <span class="percent">[0s
        </td>
        <td style="" class="rightalign">
            99.973 %<div class="colorflag" style="background-color:#00c000">&nbsp;</div><br>
            0.027 %<div class="colorflag" style="background-color:#00c000">&nbsp;</div>
        </td>
        <td style="">
            <span class="percent">[44628]</span><br>
            <span class="percent">[12]</span>
        </td>

</tr>
<!-- Template Sensorlist Dataline No Graph.htm -->
```

I have no clue how to extract only the data I need, I could look for data between []'s and calculate the % up-time value but if it's already done how can I pull only the data I need?  Different tables have more or less information.

Comment: Normally, HTML is parsed and the values are extracted using various DOM selectors or enumeration, there are [lots of examples](https://www.google.com/#q=stackoverflow+PowerShell+to+extract+data+from+HTML)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would say :

-First, try to see if the root node of the XML is always the same.

-If that's the case, then use following command :

```
(New-Object System.Net.WebClient).DownloadString($URL)
```

Parse the result and look for the opening and closing tag of the root node.
Once you have it, you can send only that part into an XML variable.

Then, you can use PowerShell tools to parse your XML, and find the lowest percentage. But I don't see with your example how you will bind your percentage to an item...

Comment: Very close to what I used; I ended up with:

<pre><code>$resp = $req.GetResponse()<br>
$reqstream = $resp.GetResponseStream()<br>
$stream = new-object System.IO.StreamReader $reqstream<br>
$result = $stream.ReadToEnd()<br>
</code></pre>